# Reemplazar el valor NULL por el valor 0 en una consulta sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

Tengo la siguiente consulta que me devuelve un numero de peticiones cerradas agrupadas por mes y año

```
SELECT DATEPART(year,fecha)año, DATEPART(month,fecha)mes, count(*) as 'cerradas'
FROM TABLA  
WHERE ti.fec_cierre BETWEEN @FEC_INICIO AND @FEC_FIN
    AND ind_sugerencia = 'S'
GROUP BY DATEPART(year,fecha), DATEPART(month,fecha)
```

con la siguiente declaración de fechas

```
DECLARE @FEC_INICIO DATETIME = '20190301'
DECLARE @FEC_FIN DATETIME = '20220801'
```

Funciona correctamente salvo cuando no existen valores en el mes y el año por el que agrupo.
Cuando no devuelve ningún valor para un mes concreto, no se pinta nada.
Lo que me gustaría es que en lugar de saltarse un mes para el que no hay valores, devolviese un 0.
Pintase por pantalla todos los meses y en otra columna el valor 0 si no hay ninguna o el valor correspondiente si existen para ese mes.

¿Es posible agruparlo de alguna manera para pintar un 0 en lugar de NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar **[ISNULL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp)** el que se encarga de setear un valor por defecto si éste es nulo.

```
SELECT ISNULL(campo, 0) FROM Tabla
```

Nos comentas que tal te va! :D

Comment: Esa opción ya la probé pero seguían sin salir los valores como 0. Desconozco si es por usar datepart o por el group by utliziado

Comment: @Manu y si pruebas realizando `ISNULL((select count(*) from tabla), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr esto, necesitas crear una tabla de números:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 1 as Number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Number+1
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE Number < 12
)
SELECT Number INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM CTE
```

Ahora hacer algo como esto:

```
SELECT coalesce (año,0) Año, coalesce(A.mes,0)Mes, Cerradas
FROM (SELECT    Number Mes FROM dbo.Numbers
            
) n
LEFT JOIN ( 
        select año, mes, Cerradas,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Mes ) AS Conteo
        from
        (
            SELECT DATEPART(year,fecha)año, DATEPART(month,fecha)mes,count(*) as 'cerradas'
            FROM TABLA  
            WHERE ti.fec_cierre BETWEEN @FEC_INICIO AND @FEC_FIN
                AND ind_sugerencia = 'S'
            GROUP BY DATEPART(year,fecha), DATEPART(month,fecha)
        )t
   ) A
on n.Mes = A.Conteo
order by  Año, Mes
```

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una de las posibles soluciones. Aunque primero el escenario.

```
Create Table dbo.tabla
             (
             id             int Identity(1, 1)
           , fecha          date
           , ind_sugerencia char(1)
           , fec_cierre     date
             );
GO
Insert into dbo.Tabla 
(fecha, ind_sugerencia, fec_cierre)
values
('20190301','S','20190301'),
('20190301','S','20190301'),
('20190301','N','20190301'),
('20190401','S','20190401'),
('20190401','N','20190401'),
('20190501','S','20190501'),
('20190901','S','20190901'),
('20200101','S','20200101'),
('20200201','S','20200201'),
('20200301','N','20200301'),
('20200401','S','20200401'),
('20200501','S','20200501');
GO
```

Con el escenario montado:

```
DECLARE @FEC_INICIO DATETIME = '20190301';
DECLARE @FEC_FIN DATETIME = '20220801';
with c1 as (
    select tbl.n from
          (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) tbl(n)
    ), c2 as (select 1 as c from c1 cross join c1 as t
    ), c3 as (select 1 as c from c2 cross join c2 as t
    ), c4 as (select 1 as c from c3 cross join c3 as t
    ), nums as (select row_number() 
    over(order by (select null)) as rownum from c4)
    , interval as (
    select top(datediff(month,@FEC_INICIO, @FEC_FIN)) + rownum  as n
    from nums)
    , meses as (
        select cast(dateadd(month,n-1,@FEC_INICIO) as date)
        as fecha 
            from interval
    ), datos as (
    /* origen de los datos */
   SELECT DATEPART(year,fecha)año, DATEPART(month,fecha)mes, count(*) as [cerradas]
        FROM TABLA  
        WHERE fec_cierre BETWEEN @FEC_INICIO AND @FEC_FIN
                AND ind_sugerencia = 'S'
        GROUP BY DATEPART(year,fecha), DATEPART(month,fecha)
    ), datosdate as (
    select datefromparts(d.año, d.mes, 1) as fecha 
            , [cerradas]
     from datos d
     )
    select m.fecha
         , isnull(d.cerradas,0) as [cerradas]
     from meses m
    left join datosdate d on m.fecha = d.fecha
    order by m.fecha asc;
```

[image: Salida]

La solución consiste, en generar una serie de intervalos de números (conjunto nums) y escoger los valores entre este intervalo (conjunto interval).

Con esta parte de la query:

```
DECLARE @FEC_INICIO DATETIME = '20190301';
DECLARE @FEC_FIN DATETIME = '20220801';
with c1 as (
    select tbl.n from
          (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) tbl(n)
    ), c2 as (select 1 as c from c1 cross join c1 as t
    ), c3 as (select 1 as c from c2 cross join c2 as t
    ), c4 as (select 1 as c from c3 cross join c3 as t
    ), nums as (select row_number() 
    over(order by (select null)) as rownum from c4)
    , interval as (
    select top(datediff(month,@FEC_INICIO, @FEC_FIN)) + rownum  as n
    from nums)
    , meses as (
        select cast(dateadd(month,n-1,@FEC_INICIO) as date)
        as fecha 
            from interval
    )
    select * from meses;
```

[image: Salida2]

Tenemos los meses entre el rango. Luego los mezclamos con los datos reales.

[Todos los items en un intervalo](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/12/21/todos-los-items-por-mes-y-ano-aunque-no-tuviera/)